# Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Tags: php

```
    $sql = "SELECT `id`, `nome`, `nivel` FROM `usuarios` WHERE (`usuario` = '".$usuario ."') AND (`senha` = '". sha1($senha) ."') AND (`ativo` = 1) LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) != 1) {

        echo "Login inválido!"; exit;

    } else {
        //
    }
```

Erro:

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
```

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que sua query possui algum erro, então `mysqli_query` retorna `false` e ao passar esse valor para `mysqli_num_rows` causa o erro

Antes do `if` imprime na tela o comando (`echo $sql;`) e tente executar o mesmo no phpMyAdmin, MySQL Workbench ou algo assim, esses softwares irão mostrar mais exatamente onde está o erro

Comment: Apareceu isso aqui mano:
SELECT `id`, `nome`, `nivel` FROM `usuarios` WHERE (`usuario` = 'teste') AND (`senha` = '40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef') AND (`ativo` = 1) LIMIT 1

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /storage/ssd5/850/7211850/public_html/validacao.php on line 30
Login inválido!

Answer (score 0):

Para saber quantas linhas vieram, pode tentar fazer assim como este trecho:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$arrDados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$nLinhas = count($arrDados);

if ($nLinhas == 1) {
    echo "Login Ok!";
    // Continua sua programação.
} else {
    echo "Login inválido!"; exit;
}
```

Comment: Deu esse erro agora:

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /storage/ssd5/850/7211850/public_html/validacao.php on line 29